# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carouFredSel'

Tags: jquery, wordpress, caroufredsel

I'm trying to create a slider in WordPress. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

    // Enqueue Flexslider Files
    function wd_slider_scripts() {
            //wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

            wp_enqueue_style( 'carouFredSel-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/client_slider/css/style.css' );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'carouFredSel-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/inc/client_slider/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0-packed.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'touchSwipe-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/inc/client_slider/js/jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wd_slider_scripts' );

    // Initialize Slider
    function wd_slider_initialize() { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery('#partners-slider .slider-holder2').carouFredSel({
                    align: 'center',
                    items: {
                        visible: "variable",
                        width: "variable"
                    },
                    scroll: 1,
                    prev: ".prev-arr",
                    next: ".next-arr"
                });
            </script>
    <?php }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wd_slider_initialize' );

    // Create Client Slider
    function wd_client_template() {

            // Query Arguments
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'clients',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5
            );      

            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Check if the Query returns any posts
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                // Start the Client Slider ?>
                <section></section>

                <section class="partners">

                <div id="partners-slider">
                    <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" style="display: block; text-align: start; float: none; position: relative; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; z-index: auto; width: 100%; height: 52px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
                        <div class="slider-holder2" style="text-align: left; float: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: -188.89493620243093px; margin: 0px; width: 4105px; height: 52px; z-index: auto;">

                                    <?php
                                    // The Loop
                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                                            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-arr">
                    <a class="prev-arr arr-btn" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
                    <a class="next-arr arr-btn" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
                </div>

                </section>

            <?php }

            // Reset Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

I am facing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carouFredSel'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you narrowed down your code to pinpoint which part is causing the error? What's the context? Have you installed the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is indicating that the code is trying to call a method called `carouFredSel` on something, but the method doesn't exist. Looking at your code, I can see you've tried to call that method on a jQuery object:

```
jQuery('#partners-slider .slider-holder2').carouFredSel({ /* ... */ });
```

[The documentation for carouFredSel](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel#jumpNav-3) seems to indicate that you're using it correctly:

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel();
```

So I think the first thing to check is whether you have actually included the script for it as shown in [the documentation](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel#jumpNav-1):

```
<script src="jquery.carouFredSel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```